# XSLT: Test if string is contained in a sequence

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have two sequences of strings. I wanna wether get a sequence which is reduced by those items, which are also in sequence 2; or to compare those two sequences and get the information, if at least one item of sequence 1 is also in sequence 2.
A simple compare ( $seq1 = $seq2 ) works for me only with a sequence of numbers, or am I doing something wrong?

Glad about any help! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `=` operator should suffice, see example http://xsltransform.net/gWmuiJ6 which does

```
  <xsl:variable name="seq1" select="'foo', 'bar', 'foobar'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="seq2" select="'a', 'foo', 'b'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="seq3" select="'a', 'b', 'c'"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$seq1 = $seq2, $seq1 = $seq3"/>
```

and outputs `true false`.

If you want some value based intersection then see also http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_value-intersect.html.

Comment: Thanks!! Works :)) I did not see that I made a mistake, one sequence-data-type was wrong.

Comment: A Big Thanks for this solution.